# I am creating a products page for my site using python django and postgresql.I am having a problem in comparing fields from two tables

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Currently in a database i have two tables 1.Category(id , type) and 2.Products(id,category,name,price).
I want to display the product only when the "type of category" is same as "category of products".
This is how i am proceeding but its showing error.

```
                         {% for i in types %}
                         {% for j in prods %}

                            {% if i.type== j.category %}

                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img src="{{j.disimage.url}}" alt="">
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-caption">
                                
                                <h4><a href="#">{{j.name}}</a></h4>
                                <div class="price">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>RS {{j.currentprice}}</li>
                                        <li class="discount">RS {{j.originalprice}}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
```

this line is showing error.{% if i.type== j.category %}

here is models.py

```
  from django.db import models
  from datetime import datetime
  from django.utils import timezone

  class Category(models.Model):
      type=models.CharField(max_length=30)

  class Product(models.Model):
      category=models.CharField(max_length=30)

      name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
      currentprice=models.IntegerField()
      disimage=models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
```

This is the error that i am getting:
Could not parse the remainder: '==' from 'i.type=='

Please tell me how to implement it.Thanks

Comment: can you show your models ?

Comment: from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Category(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Product(models.Model):
    category=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    currentprice=models.IntegerField()
    disimage=models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')

Comment: please include the models in your post not in the comment

Comment: done that.Please check now

Comment: I think it will be better if you keep relation between these two models.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that and how does that work.

Comment: what error you are getting now ?

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '==' from 'i.type=='

Comment: try giving space between i.type and ==

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful in future if relationships are used. Here's how a ManyToManyField relationship can be used:

```
  from django.db import models
  from datetime import datetime
  from django.utils import timezone

  class Category(models.Model):
      type=models.CharField(max_length=30)

  class Product(models.Model):
      category=models.ManyToManyField(Category, ...., related_name='products')

      name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
      currentprice=models.IntegerField()
      disimage=models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
```

In your template:

```
{% for type in types %}
  {% for each_product in type.products.all %}
    <div class="product-img">
      <img src="{{each_product.disimage.url}}" alt="">    
    </div>
    <div class="product-caption">
      <h4><a href="#">{{each_product.name}}</a></h4>
        <div class="price">
          <ul>
            <li>RS {{each_product.currentprice}}</li>
            <li class="discount">RS {{each_product.originalprice}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Generally if we dont use related_name, we use lowercase(modelname) + _set like below:

```
type.product_set.all
```

Comment: This is still not working for me.I think i was unable to express my problem.

Comment: what i want to do is that for eg. in category table in type i add 1)shirts  2)pants and in products table in category i type shirts so now i want to display the product with category shirt under shirts only and not pants.    Your solution displays the product shirt under all types

Comment: can u pls help .

Comment: No it will display shirts. I need more info. unless i cant help

Comment: what all should i tell you..I will add in my question above

Comment: the above many to many code will work and show the details of all products in shirts category. And display all the products in pants category.

Comment: yes but i want to display the products that are having category shirts only not all products and in pants only the products with category pants.

Comment: try giving space between i.type and ==

Comment: ya did that butit still does not put the products under specific category that i want it in

Comment: if you need specific category, you should filter that specific category, like category.objects.filter(type='shirt', .......)

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved.
There were two problems

1. The spaces
2. I was using multiple loops for the same model so i guess the inner one wasnt being executed the way it should have.
   Thanks for the help .